# How to get the typed value in v-select component?

Tags: vue.js, v-select

I am using the vue-select component in my Vue CLI project. The code is following:

```
<v-select @keypress.native="getResult()" :options="category_array" v-model="selected" :clearable="false"></v-select>
```

Now the issue is, the data "selected" is getting updated when I am selecting any value from the dropdown, not when I am typing anything in the component. I need to get the typed value from the component. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: You can make use of combobox https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/

Comment: there is also same issue